# Looking for a good summary of technologies and/or frameworks for Silverlight/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, frameworks, reference

I am just now delving into the world Silverlight.  I am able to accomplish a lot but I tend to do things "The Hard Way"; writting a bunch of custom code and whatnot.  Occasionally, I stumble upon technologies or frameworks that make me slap my head and die a little inside as they do exactly what I am after and can be done in minutes, not hours.

A good example of this was MEF (Managed Extension Framework).  This took my complicated "plugin" mechanism I had created in Silverlight and boiled it down into a couple of basic steps.  It's great.

My question is, where can I find a good resource that just provides a list of relevent topics to a subject (like silverlight) and a breif description of what the technology/framework is and possibly how it can be used?  I don't care about the details, I can look those up anywhere.  I just want to know what is available to me.  In other words, what tools can I use to build better code faster?

Just this high level summary of meaningful technology (to a topic of course....meaningful is subjective) could save people so much time.

Is there a resource out there like this?

Comment: Read blogs, read MSDN Magazine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) from the Patterns & Practices group at Microsoft.  It is a collection of documentation, advice on best practices, and libraries of code that make life easier in Inversion of Control architectures such as MEF.  It also talk about the MVVM pattern and other patterns to consider.

For example, one challenge when working with MEF is how do you get two separate modules to talk to each other, or respond to the same events?  Prism has an event agregator service that lets separate modules subscribe to or publish events without knowing who is on the other end of the connection.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for something a little more general in nature but this is great.  It covers the majority of the topics I am currently after.  This will be a great start!